# How to style seperate words in button_to tag?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, button

Basically I have two questions which are both related- how do I style separate words in a button_to tag.

"text".html_safe does not seem to work for a button_to tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [API Docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to)

```
<%= button_to [:make_happy, @user] do %>
  Make happy <strong><%= @user.name %></strong>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you. works perfectly. I guess that should always be the first place to look for answers. My bad